# JS : Copy Text with Image using clipboard to slack

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, slack

I am trying to copy an image with a text and paste to slack. It works when i try to copy it to notepad but wont work when i copy the same to slack.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const out = document.getElementById("out");


btn.addEventListener("click", async() => {
  try {
    const html = `
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300">
          <p>This should work</p>
        `;

    const data = [
      new ClipboardItem({
        "text/html": new Blob([html], {
          type: "text/html"
        })
      })
    ];

    navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
      () => {
        out.innerText = "Copied to clipb!";
      },
      (err) => {
        out.innerText = "Error: " + err;
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    out.innerText = "Error: " + err;
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Click Copy, then paste into Word/Teams/Slack</p>
<button id="btn" type="button">Copy HTML (works)</button>

<pre id="out"></pre>
```

The above snippet works perfectly for notepad but the copy doesnt work, when i paste it on slack.

Not sure if it has to do something with HTML.

Comment: [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/) doesn't have `ClipboardItem`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I guess they're using [`ClipboardItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardItem), not sure why OP has tagged [tag:clipboard.js], I'm guessing they've done that by mistake.